# Showing $\displaystyle{\zeta(3)=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(2n+1)\zeta(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, riemann-zeta

I want to show the following infinite series representation for $\zeta(3)$ which I stumbled across on accident.
$$\zeta(3)=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(2n+1)\zeta(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}}$$
Here is my attempt so far. By the series representation of $\zeta(2n+1)$,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(2n+1)\zeta(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2n+1}} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}k^{2n+1}}
\end{align*}$$
and I am stuck. Evaluating the second sum using wolfram gives me,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}k^{2n+1}}=\frac{16k(12k^2+1)}{(4k^2-1)^3}$$
for $\vert k\vert>1/2$, turning the problem into finding the infinite sum of some polynomial fraction, which I still can't evaluate.

Looking at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) for $\zeta(3)$ I see Euler gave the series representation,
$$\zeta(3)=\frac{\pi^2}{7}\left(1-4\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2k)}{2^{2k}(2k+1)(2k+2)}\right)$$
which some what resembles mine, so I'm guessing there's some trick I don't know of.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you have $\zeta(3)$ on both sides?

Comment: Have you tried partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: @Ilya. Oh you are right. Then I guess the series has no meaning?

Comment: Well, it is still some dependence

Comment: Note that $\frac{4k(12k^2+1)}{(4k^2-1)^3}=\frac1{(2k+1)^3}+\frac1{(2k-1)^3}-\frac1{(2k+1)^2}+\frac1{(2k-1)^2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2k-1)^3} = \frac7{8}\zeta(3)$, your answer can be directly deduced by your last step.

Comment: @Nanayajitzuki. How would I evaluate the other terms?

Comment: @bob $(2k-1)^2$ and $(2k+1)^2$ will be cancelled out by telescoping, leaving the first item, and the $(2k+1)^3$ is just an one-item shift of $(2k-1)^3$ yet lack of the first item, all those will be cancelled out, result in two $(2k-1)^3$ sums.

Comment: @Nanayajitzuki. Thanks I see it now. Do you know how $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(2n+1)}{2^{2n-2}k^{2n+1}}=\frac{16k(12k^2+1)}{(4k^2-1)^3}$$ can be done by hand?

Comment: @bob Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2n(2n+1)x^{2n-1}$ is just the second derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n+1}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$, and you find this sum by let $x=1/(2k)$ (with a little change on the coefficient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|z|<1$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\zeta(n+1)z^n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-z}-\frac1k\right)=-\gamma-\psi(1-z)$$ (seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula), respectively; the first equality is easy to get after inserting $\zeta(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-n-1}$ and summing over $n$). Extracting the even part, we obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\zeta(2n+1)z^{2n}=-\gamma-\frac12\big(\psi(1-z)+\psi(1+z)\big).$$

Now multiply by $z$ and take the second derivative: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n(2n+1)\zeta(2n+1)z^{2n-1}=\psi'(1-z)-\psi'(1+z)-\frac z2\big(\psi''(1-z)+\psi''(1+z)\big).$$

The sum *in the title of the OP* is obtained at $z=1/2$. For $n>0$ we have $$(-1)^{n+1}\psi^{(n)}(1-z)=n!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k-z)^{n+1}}$$ (taking the $n$-th derivative of the equality at the beginning), hence
$$\psi'(1/2)-\psi'(3/2)=4,\\\psi''(1/2)-\psi''(3/2)=-16,\\\psi''(1/2)=-16\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(2k-1)^3}=-14\zeta(3).$$

That's sufficient.

Comment: Essentially, this answer boils down to using the definition of $\zeta$ and switching the order of summations (the digamma function appears only as a "known thing", with none of its specific properties used).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really like how the digamma function appears (even though none of its properties were used). Also, the proof for the other series (by Euler) is very neat, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

A proof of the mentioned series (by Euler), for completeness. We have, for $|z|<1$, $$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\zeta(2n)z^{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z^2}{k^2-z^2}=1-\pi z\cot\pi z$$ (the first equality after $\zeta(2n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2n}$ and summing over $n$; the second one is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Partial_fraction_expansion), or obtained as the logarithmic derivative of the [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Infinite_product_expansion) for the sine function). Then $$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2n)z^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\int_0^z(z-t)(1-\pi t\cot\pi t)\,dt$$ and, if we put $z=1/2$ and substitute $t=x/\pi$, we obtain $$S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2^{2n}(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\int_0^{1/2}(1-2t)(1-\pi t\cot\pi t)\,dt\\=\frac14-\frac1\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx+\frac2{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cot x\,dx.$$

These integrals are evaluated using integration by parts and the Fourier series $$-\log|\sin x|=\log 2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos 2nx}{n}.$$

With $\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos 2nx\,dx=\frac{(-1)^n-1}{4n^2}$ (again, using i.b.p.), we easily get $$\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx=\frac\pi2\log2,\qquad\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cot x\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}4\log2-\frac78\zeta(3),$$ hence $S=\frac14\left(1-\frac7{\pi^2}\zeta(3)\right)$ as expected.